# How does gnuplot skip irrelevent column in plot?

Tags: gnuplot

I have a data file like this

# Time A irrelevent_col B 
1 2 3 4 
2 3 4 5 
3 4 5 6 
4 5 6 7

I am trying to plot two lines Time vs A, Time vs B with labels "A" and "B". How can I skip the "irrelevent_col" column?
I did the following, but the code still plots the "irrelevent_col" column. Shouldn't the ? : operator gets ride of that column?

```
set datafile commentschars "!!!"    
plot for [i=2:4] filename using 1:(columnhead(i+1) ne "irrelevent_col" ? column(i) : 1/0) title columnhead(i+1)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly your question:

```
plot "filename" using 1:2 title "A" with lines,\
     "filename" using 1:4 title "B" with lines
```

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning it explicitly. I am looking for solutions can do iteration. My actual file has many columns and I want to filter out some irrelevant column using ? : operation.

Comment: No problem. You could consider using `awk` or `cut` to remove the unwanted columns beforehand, then proceed with a loop of the remaining columns.

Comment: That's a good suggestion. Though I am still puzzled why my proposed solution doesn't work. Thanks anyway. @Vinicius Placco

Answer (score 0):

Let me repeat what I've understood from your question:
You have a large number of columns and you want to plot them all in a loop, but exclude a single column (or a few) by name.

Of course, you can specify all columns you ***do want*** to plot, like in @ViniciusPlacco's answer, however, as I understand that's what you wanted to avoid, since you have many more columns in your real data. You can also always use external tools to pre-process your data, but here I would like to suggest a *gnuplot-only* and hence platform-independent solution.

Why your solution is not working, I can only speculate: I guess using columnheader twice in a plot iteration creates problems (at least for gnuplot<=5.2). But I could be wrong. But as I will show below, your solution will work for gnuplot>=5.4.0.

Furthermore, you want to specify the columns by header not by column number.
In addition, your header line starts with the comment char `'#'`, but you can easily change that to access the columnheader information.

In the example below you can specify a list of several headers which you don't want to plot. Maybe the script(s) can be further simplified.

**Script:** (works for gnuplot>=5.4.0, July 2020)

```
### exclude some columns by header from plotting loop (gnuplot>=5.4.0)
reset session

$Data <<EOD
# Time A  B  C  D  E
  1    2  3  4  5  6
  2    3  4  5  6  7
  3    4  5  6  7  8
  4    5  6  7  8  9
EOD

set datafile commentschars ''       # no commentchar
set key top left noenhanced noautotitle

inList(w,list) = int(sum[_i=1:words(list)] w eq word(list,_i))
doNotPlot      = 'B C'
color          = 1 

plot for [col=2:6] $Data u 1:((b=inList(myHeader=columnhead(col+1),doNotPlot)) ? \
     NaN : ($0==1?color=color+1:0, column(col))) w lp pt 7 lc color ti (b ? '' : myHeader)
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

For older gnuplot versions <5.4.0 you need a different approach:

- get all headers into a string
- specify all your headers of the columns you ***don't want*** to plot in a string
- for gnuplot>=5.0.0, subtract two lists and keep the *column numbers* for the header you ***do want*** to plot

**Script:** (works for gnuplot>=5.2.2, Nov. 2017; result same as graph above)

```
### exclude some columns by header from plotting loop (gnuplot>=5.2.2)
reset session

$Data <<EOD
# Time A  B  C  D  E
  1    2  3  4  5  6
  2    3  4  5  6  7
  3    4  5  6  7  8
  4    5  6  7  8  9
EOD

set datafile commentschars ''       # no commentchar
set key top left noenhanced noautotitle

inList(w,list) = int(sum[_i=1:words(list)] w eq word(list,_i))
doNotPlot      = 'B C'

myHeaders = ''
color = 1
plot for [col=2:6] $Data u 1:((b=inList(myHeader=columnhead(col+1),doNotPlot)) ? NaN : \
     ($0==1 ? (color=color+1, myHeaders=myHeaders.' '.myHeader) : 0, column(col))) w lp pt 7 lc color, \
     for [i=1:color] NaN w lp pt 7 lc i ti word(myHeaders,i)
### end of script
```

**Script:** (works for gnuplot>=5.0.0, Jan. 2015; result same as graph above)

```
### exclude some columns by header from plotting loop (gnuplot>=5.0.0)
reset session

$Data <<EOD
# Time A  B  C  D  E
  1    2  3  4  5  6
  2    3  4  5  6  7
  3    4  5  6  7  8
  4    5  6  7  8  9
EOD

set datafile commentschars ''       # no commentchar
set datafile separator "\n"         # or another character which is not in the header line
stats $Data u (allHeaders = strcol(1)[2:]) ever ::::0 nooutput   # get header line into string
set datafile commentschar           # reset to default
set datafile separator whitespace   # ditto

inList(w,list)             = int(sum[_i=1:words(list)] w eq word(list,_i))
subtractLists(list1,list2) = (_s=' ', sum[_j=1:words(list1)] (_s0=word(list1,_j), \
                              inList(_s0,list2) ? 0 : (_s=_s._s0.' ', \
                              myColNos=myColNos.' '._j), 0), _s)
doNotPlot  = 'B C'
myColNos   = ''
myHeaders  = subtractLists(allHeaders,doNotPlot)
myColNo(i) = column((word(myColNos,i)))
set key top left noenhanced noautotitle

plot for [i=2:words(myHeaders)] $Data u 1:(myColNo(i)) w lp pt 7 ti word(myHeaders,i)
### end of script
```